# Laggy animations and scrolling on website

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, css-transitions

Here is  [My website](http://www.bsrp.eu/tijdelijk/index.php) and I use a lot of animations in it, the problem is that the (special) scrolling is a bit laggy and also when you open the slides at the 3rd and 4th page it opens up very laggy.

I tried using sites for performance optimization and it gave an A to almost everything.

Should I just use less animations to make everything go smooth again or is it something else? Cause I have seen websites with more animations go smoother but that could be cause they use some sort of framework which I'm not using.

The code of the laggy animations:

```
#Animation1{
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100vw - 128px);
    transition: ease-out 1s;
    z-index: 9;
}
#Animation{
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100vw - 128px);
    transition: ease-out 1s;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

JQuery code that do something with scrolling:

```
//Scrolling goes to next anchor
(function () {
    var delay = false;

    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (delay) return;

        delay = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            delay = false
        }, 800);

        var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        var a = document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");
        if (wd < 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if (t >= window.innerHeight * 0.1) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if (t < -window.innerHeight * 0.1) break;
            }
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
        }, 800);

    });
})();

// Code that does something when on .. height of the page
$(function () {
    //FOOTER
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 3.01) {
           -- do this
        }
    //CONTACT
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 3) {
            -- do this
        }
    //ABOUT US
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 1.3) {
            -- do this
        }
    }).scroll()
});
```

Comment: the problem is definitely due to the animations. but please share the code of your animations for more help. thanks

Comment: @viCky added the code for the ones were the animations are acting laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your animations. When you use elements like left, top, right and bottom, or when you alter the size of elements then the browser has to compute the new style and then repaint them for the user to see.

It is suggested to use transform and/or translate to move your elements while animating them.

```
div {
    -ms-transform: translate(50px, 100px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(50px, 100px);
}
```

That being said, I believe it would be better to shift to GreenSock Timeline. This is a simple to use and light weight jquery animation library. Once you have integrated this, your website will float smoothly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My element starts somewere out of the page (`left: -100vw`) so if I want to do the css like you say and make it start out of the page I should make the element start with `transform: translate(-100vw, 0);` right?

Comment: yes. You can use css animation for defining the original and final position.

Comment: again i suggest you to use greensock. There you wont need to calculate the  final px. Greensock will move your element around from its relative position on the screen. Checkout their homepage animation: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/yhEmn

Comment: Is it really worth to take that if I would only use it on 2 elements?

Comment: Shift to greensock for all the animations, including fade in of images, it will definitely make a difference and you wont need to write too much code for it. Use their lite version for your use. 
Secondly, i just checked that you jquery is also leading to jitter in the scroll. Try scrolling with the jquery commented and everything should work fine. Use ScrollMagic with Greensock for a smooth website.

Comment: How if we use CSS variable but a sure variable in the transform property? Is it like left, top, right, and bottom?